# How do big black hole kicks out small black hole?

Tags: black-holes, collision, event-horizon

I read that when 2 black holes collide they will either merge into a single black holes or recoil and the less massive black hole will be thrown out, I'm thinking of gravitational slingshot whereby spacecraft can save fuel by approaching the planet from behind (in the same direction as the planet is moving around the Sun to get a boost of speed). If this is not the case how else to explain the recoil?

Comment: if the description says "thrown out" it is more than an elastic collision of the slingshot,  they must have joined and General Relativity has to be used, not classical physics slingshots.

Comment: @annav: took me a while to find the online article from Space Answer and here's the paragraph written: "And scientists at the Max Planck Institute for extraterrestrial Physics have observed a black hole being ‘kicked out’ of its parent galaxy through interacting with a bigger black hole."

Comment: It is possible, but it would still need general relativity for the initial trajectories, once out of the strong gravitational field of each other it would approximate a sling shot, because low gravitational fields follow Newton's gravity.

Comment: “Interacting” doesn’t necessarily mean “colliding”.